# Fixed menu at bottom until a certain point and then at top for rest of page

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu which stays relative until the top of the window scrolls to it and then it becomes fixed from there seamlessly but people on smaller screens can't see it so I need a way to make it fixed at the bottom until it reaches the point where it currently sits under the main image (680 pixels from the top of the window), then becomes relative until the top of the screen hits it again (ie has scrolled 680 pixels) and continues fixed at the top for the rest of the page, the code I'm currently using is;

```
$(window).load(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(e) {

if ($(window).scrollTop() > 680) { 

    $('.nav').css({

            position: 'fixed',

            top: '0'

        })

        $('body').css({

            margin: '105px 0px 0px 0px'

        });

    } else {

        $('.nav').css({

            position: 'relative'

        })

        $('body').css({

            margin: '0px 0px 0px 0px'

        });

    }

});
});
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle to make it easier to visualize your problem.

Comment: I have set it up here but the code doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/n4xvuk8j/1/ but you can see how the black bar can't be seen on a small screen so I want it fixed to the bottom until it reaches it position at the bottom of the top box and then stay relative until the top of the window reaches it where it will then stay fixed to the top.

Comment: Two things that come to mind: First off, the `jQuery(document).ready` is enough, you need to remove the `$(window).load`. Second, the logic is switched around, it needs to be `$(window).scrollTop() < 680`.

Comment: Oh, and the reason why the fiddle doesn't work is because you forgot to select jQuery in the "Frameworks & Extensions" dropdown at the top left. :)

Comment: Sorry thanks that would explain that! :)  The logic isn't switched, it's working now here and I've made the top box bigger to explain the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/n4xvuk8j/3/ - when you scroll down the bar attaches to the top after 1400 pixels (was 680 and I increased it) and continues for the rest of the page fixed at the top, but what I need to do is initially have it fixed at the bottom of the page until it reaches it's position below the top box (ie position relative) and stay there until it attaches fixed to the top. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here's your solution:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('body')
        .toggleClass('top', scrollTop > 1400)
        .toggleClass('visible', scrollTop <= 1400 && scrollTop > 1505 - $(window).height());
});
```

```css
.nav {
    width:100%;
    height:105px;
    background:#333;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.visible .nav {
    position: static;
}

.top .nav {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 0;
}

body.top {
    margin-top: 105px;
}
```

The navigation is fixed to the bottom per default. It goes to the top once 1400 pixels are passed. And when we're higher up than 1400 pixels but lower than 1400 pixels plus the navigation height (makes 1505) minus the height of the window, we let the navigation scroll along. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4xvuk8j/4/